# How to reference another dataset inside of a table in ssrs?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, aggregate

I have a table that is referencing a dataset called 'InvoiceHeader' and using fields from that dataset. I want to be able to reference another dataset called 'TaxRate' from inside the current table. I'm attempting to do :

`= First(Fields!CurrencyDisplay.Value, "TaxRate")`

My error is:

> The Value expression for the text box ‘textbox5’ refers directly to
>   the field ‘TAXRATE’ without specifying a dataset aggregate

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL? `= First(Fields!CurrencyDisplay.Value, "TaxRate")` looks like a spreadsheet function/query

Comment: Values comes from an sql query into ssrs

Comment: "Values comes from an sql query into ssrs" SSRS as in SQL Server Reporting Services ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the LOOKUP function.

Without knowing what is in your datasets I can't give a complete answer but I assume there is some common element between the two datasets. Lets assume you have a `RegionID` in your first dataset and the same ID appears in your seconds dataset called `rID` (I've used different names for clarity, they may be the same though). In this case your expression would be something like.

```
=LOOKUP(Fields!RegionID.Value, Fields!rID.Value, Fields!CurrencyDisplay.Value, "DataSet2")
```

This basically reads...

Using the RegionID field from DataSet1, find the matching value in the rID column in DataSet2 and return the value found in the CurrencyDisplay column.

Comment: So i have to join the datasets the same way i would an sql table. I only want to  concatenate the header with a value selected in my dataset. The 2 datasets don't directly link, just want to add it to the label that refers to a value from the other dataset

Comment: Can you show a small sample of data from each dataset as I'm not sure what you mean. As long as your 2nd dataset has some unique ID that you can use to select the correct row you can use anything in the first lookup parameter to point to it, even a literal.

Comment: Your answer is simple and right,

=LOOKUP(Fields!RegionID.Value, Fields!rID.Value, "Matched", "DataSet2")

It should be "Fields!rID" instead of "Fields.rID"